# using a message collector to set embed fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've got a message collector, and I'm trying to use the data collected in an embed as the title, description and embed colour. So far I've got it working so that each value returns an individual embed.

I believe this is due to the forEach in line 38, however everything else I've tried (deleting that line, returns nothing, changing to collected.messages(value) throws value is not defined, collected.messages throws its not a function) doesn't work

I'm not sure what to change it to, to get the result I'm after (which is the first answer setting the embed title, the second the embed description and the third the embed colour).

code is

````
module.exports = {
    name: "embed",
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
    const questions = [
      'What is the message title?',
      'What is the message description?',
      'What is the embed colour?',
    ]

    let counter = 0

    const filter = (m) => !m.author.bot

    const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, {
      max: questions.length,
      time: 60000 * 5, // 5m
    })

    message.channel.send(questions[counter++])
    collector.on('collect', (m) => {
      if (counter < questions.length) {
        m.channel.send(questions[counter++])
      }
    })

    collector.on('end', (collected) => {
      console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} messages`)

      if (collected.size < questions.length) {
        message.reply('The command has timed out')
        return
      }

      let counter = 0
      collected.forEach((value) => {
        console.log(value.content)
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(value.content)
            .setDescription(value.content)
            .setColor(value.content)
         
         
         let messageEmbed = message.channel.send(embed);
       
      })
      })
    }
    }```
    

Any help would be greatly appreciated
````

Answer (score 0):

all I needed to do was set a variable to see where I was in the count, then use the variable to set the fields

````
      let i = 0;
      collected.forEach((value) => {
        i++;
        if (i === 1) embed.setTitle(value.content);
        else if (i === 2) embed.setDescription(value.content);
        else if (i === 3) embed.setColor(value.content);
      })

      let messageEmbed = message.channel.send(embed);```
````